# Any way to forecast time series data using ARIMA model in python?

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting

I tried to forecast `target_price_index` using ARIMA model which is a good choice for forecasting time series. My data is monthly time series, I want to forecast `target_price_index` from data. I've worked with scikit-learn for prediction tasks, but not much knows about using `ARIMA` model on time series. To do so, I tried as follow:

**my attempt**

Here is the reproducible time-series data that I used [example data](https://jmp.sh/v/HeU73xqXrL6fossoTeuk) and [reproducible time series data on gist](https://gist.github.com/jerry-shad/425723d8ea0dbdb6fa7a72f999365996)

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
from matplotlib import pyplot
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("finaldf.csv", sep="\t")
model = ARIMA(df['target_price_index'], order=(5,1,0))
model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
print(model_fit.summary())
# plot residual errors
residuals = DataFrame(model_fit.resid)
residuals.plot()
pyplot.show()
residuals.plot(kind='kde')
pyplot.show()
print(residuals.describe())
```

but the output of the above attempt is not really satisfying because I can't see any benefits of forecasting on my time series data. Can anyone point me out is there any efficient pipeline or analytical approach to get meaningful prediction results? Any suggestion? Any possible thoughts on this? Thanks!

I also tried [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55545501/how-to-perform-time-series-analysis-that-contains-multiple-groups-in-python-usin)  in `SO` still not working for forecasting my time series data correctly. Does anyone have possible thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the full traceback

Comment: @MZ I actually figured out what went wrong and now it works fine. But to me, the current attempt is not efficient, can't get meaningful prediction output. Do you have possible thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I found a couple of problems with the code:

1. The csv file uses tabs as a separator:

   ```
   df = pd.read_csv("finaldf.csv",sep='\t')
   ```
2. When you instantiate the ARIMA model, the first parameter should be your target:

   ```
   model = ARIMA(df.target_prc_index,order=(5,1,0))
   ```